# Firebase ID questions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A friend of mine built the firebase realtime database for the app we were working on, now that he is no longer on this app do I need to make a new database with current bundle ID so that it matches the Xcode's app or does that not matter?

Comment: You can make a new database in Firebase and drag the new *GoogleService-Info.plist* to you app in XCode. Your app will then talk to the new database. But that leads to the question(s), why are you asking - was he the only admin? Do you need to maintain your data? Can you clarify the parameters around your question?

Comment: is there a way to copy a database and bring it into a new firebase project to create the new plist? I have the app in beta with TestFlight and it is not populating any information on the cell phone.......assumed this may be the problem. Have updated all cocoa pods also

Comment: Is there a way? Sure, but it would have to be at the app level - there's no button in the Firebase console that says 'Copy Database'. Again though, the question and circumstances are a bit unclear. Why don't you just generate a plist from the existing database and put that in your project?